# ¿Error con el foreignkey en c# EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo una tabla llamada ***Ubicacion*** y tiene relacionadas varias tablas pero al realizar un `select` a la misma me genera el siguiente error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'El ForeignKeyAttribute de la propiedad 'columna' en el tipo 'Integrado.Domain.Entities.Ubicacion' no es válido. No se encuentra el nombre de la clave externa 'Codbloque' en el tipo dependiente 'Integrado.Domain.Entities.Ubicacion'. El valor Name debe ser una lista separada por comas de los nombres de propiedad de clave externa.'
```

Esta es mi clase de repositorio que contiene el metodo listar

```
public IQueryable<Columna> comboColumna()
        {
            return this._db.Set<Columna>().Distinct().Select(x => new Columna() { codColumna = x.codColumna, nomColumna = x.nomColumna });
        }
```

Esta es mi clase context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ubicacion>().HasRequired(x=>x.ruma);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ubicacion>().HasRequired(x => x.bloque);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ubicacion>().HasRequired(x => x.columna);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ubicacion>().HasRequired(x => x.categoria);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Mi clase Ubicacion

```
[Table("TaUbicaciones")]
    public class Ubicacion
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Codubicacion")]
        public int codUbicacion { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codruma")]
        public Ruma ruma { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codbloque")]
        public Bloque bloque { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codcat")]
        public Categoria categoria { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codcolumna")]
        public Columna columna { get; set; }

        [Column("separacion")]
        public string separacion { get; set; }

        [Column("nivel")]
        public int nivel { get; set; }

        [Column("matriz")]
        public string matriz { get; set; }

        [Column("FlagEstado")]
        public int estado { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo que usted provee no da mucho detalle pero hay algo que noto y puede ayudar.

```
[Table("TaUbicaciones")]
    public class Ubicacion
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Codubicacion")]
        public int codUbicacion { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("Codruma")]
        public int RumaId{ get; set; }        
        public Ruma ruma { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codbloque")]
        public int BloqueId { get; set; }           
        public Bloque bloque { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codcat")]
        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public Categoria categoria { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codcolumna")]
        public int ColumnaId { get; set; }        
        public Columna columna { get; set; }

        [Column("separacion")]
        public string separacion { get; set; }

        [Column("nivel")]
        public int nivel { get; set; }

        [Column("matriz")]
        public string matriz { get; set; }

        [Column("FlagEstado")]
        public int estado { get; set; }
    }
```

Si nota agregue los IDs que representantan las ForeignKeys, porque usted no debe definir con EF una ForeignKey usando la Entidad(Clase).

Con esto usted debe resolver el problema, igual seria bueno chequeara las otras entidades, solo para confirmar que realizo el mapeo de la relacion 1:n correctamente.

Comment: Si con ello se soluciono el problema. Pero hay otra forma sin tener que poner el id, escuche de Fluent  API.

Comment: Si hay multiples formas de hacerlo, basado en su codigo encontre la solucion mas cercana. Me alegra que se resolvio su asunto, si tiene alguna otra duda puede contactarme que con gusto le ayudo. Feliz domingo!